# Get last messages for user inbox using sql

Tags: sql

i am working on user inbox. i have to retrieve last message to show in inbox, either it was from me or from my friend. i have tried every possible solution but i am not getting any result that's why i am asking here. i am still learning sql. here is my db picture 
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDbkL.png)

solution i want: example:

```
id | sent_by | sent_to | descp
42 | 3       | 7       | fdssdf
30 | 3       | 6       | sdas
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not links to images.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: stack overflow did this, i gave pic for my table..

Comment: You don't have post picture privilege (yet). Another reason to include formatted text instead!

Comment: instead of helping, most users just wanna downvote, thanks for not helping btw, If i am new user, i need some time for sure to know the correct format. this is happening for like 100 time. deleting my account. all i need is my own help

Comment: I didn't downvote. I even assisted you with some formatting. Now it's your turn!

Comment: well thanks for correcting my format, i was working on this for two days, day and night and was not getting right output, no one even helped. i know this isn't appropriate to say it here. i got it now, i helped myself and i got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but usually when you want to select the latest of something, you use `SELECT TOP 1` and `ORDER BY x DESC`

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM your_table_name
WHERE sent_by = 3
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Note that `TOP` is a product specific function, and no dbms is specified here. At least inform OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Comment: i want an inbox just like facebook one, which shows last messages received by any user